# Hiding empty custom field for images with Anchor CMS

Tags: php, custom-fields, anchor-cms

The explanation for this line is that Anchor doesn't display the image from the custom field correctly. So I had to add the missing part of the path. It works just fine, but now the problem is that I get horrendous icons on Safari when there is no image fetched in the field image:

```
<?php echo "<img src='http://www.firstpartoftheurl/" . article_custom_field('image') . "' alt=' ' height='300' >"; ?>
```

May I show this line only when the custom field is populated?
And how can I hide custom fields when they are empty?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it:

```
<?php
$image = article_custom_field('image');
if (!empty($image)) { 
echo "<img src= 'http://www.firstpartoftheurl".article_custom_field('image')."' alt='blabla ".article_title()."'>"; //if there is image show it
} else {
//if not do nothing
} ?>
```

I hope it helps. It works for me but if someone has a better solution, please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Shorter still:

```
<?php if (article_custom_field('featured-img')) :?>
      <img src="<?php echo article_custom_field('featured-img')?>" alt="<?php echo article_title(); ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

If `article_custom_field()` is not returning the full URL, there might be something up with your server configuration, because this has always worked for me. Otherwise, just prepend `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`... this is better than hard-coding the URL.

There is documentation on the function here which also explains how to use its fallback: http://anchorcms.com/docs/function-reference/articles